# How can I write a same meaning sentence without using Perfect Progressive?

Tags: tense

For Instance:

In: "I learn English.", the action "learn" started 10 years ago, and I  still learn English ***now***.

Comment: So, there are over a dozen tenses in English. Present perfect progressive is just right for expressing that situation. What's wrong with it, and how many more tenses do you want to consider to be happy?

Comment: @200_success, I learned the present simlpe and present continuous can replace future tense, so I asked if it is possible, of course, perfect progressive is suitable for that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have been learning English for ten years" is the best way to express the situation you describe. Any tense other than present perfect continuous would be not as accurate — and you'll sound like a foreigner who hasn't mastered English.

Comment: -1 just because I hate anonymous downvotes, and a downvote means I disagree.

Comment: @CarSmack In what way do you disagree? Can you offer a better answer?

Comment: Presentperfect "I've studied English for ten years." Just because I don't like progressive tenses, but I am reading up on aspect, so I'll get to answer soonish

Comment: @user6951 But you've changed the verb to one with a different lexical aspect: your "study" is atelic, but OP's "learn" is telic.